# How to get the foreground on a binary image (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've a binary picture of a person posing and I want to ignore the background (black) part and get only the foreground (the person itself, white). 
I want this to fuse the person with a different background.

I'm stucked here. I dont know how to continue:

```
mypic = imread('model1.jpg');

binarymypic = im2bw(mypic);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get the siluete of the person, and fuse this with a different background. I dont need the original background for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `A` and `B`, which are the same size, you can copy the pixels you want from `A` to `B` using a logical mask `I`:

```
B(I) = A(I);
```

In this case, `A` is mypic, `I` is `binarymypic` and `B` contains the background.

**EDIT**: Try:

```
mypic = imread('model1.jpg');
backgroundimage = imread('background.jpg');

% Check assumptions
assert(size(mypic,3) == 3, 'Expecting true colour foreground image')
assert(size(mypic,3) == 3, 'Expecting true colour background image')
assert(isequal(size(mypic), size(backgroundimage)), 'Images should have the same size')

mask = im2bw(rgb2gray(mypic));

in = reshape(mypic, [], 3);
out = reshape(backgroundimage, [], 3);
out(mask,1) = in(mask,1); % Red
out(mask,2) = in(mask,2); % Green
out(mask,3) = in(mask,3); % Blue

finalimage = reshape(out, size(backgroundimage));
imshow(finalimage)
```

Comment: So the code would be: backgroundimage(logical(binarymypic)) = mypic(logical(binarymypic). Right? How can I see it on a image? (imshow)? Thanks

Comment: I would rather write `mask = logical(im2bw(myypic)); backgroundimage(mask) = mypic(mask);` because it's clearer what the intention is.

Comment: `mypic = imread('model1.jpg');
backgroundimage = imread('background.jpg');

q = rgb2gray(mypic);
binarymypic = im2bw(q);

mask = logical(im2bw(mypic));
backgroundimage(mask) = mypic(mask);

imshow(backgroundimage)`

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? The model looks now like with a "red"-ish color

Comment: You need to copy each of the 3 colour channels separately. Unfortunately, that's not trivial. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It's VERY similar than the result I want to have but it's not exactly the same. The thing is that some pixels of the foreground image are missing on the resultant picture. But looks quite great. Thanks Nzbuu

Comment: Try setting a threshold for `im2bw`. Read the help.

Comment: Fixed! I just changed the value of the binarization from default value (which I dont know which is it) to 0.1: `mask = im2bw(rgb2gray(mypic),0.1)`